# Select values not correctly increasing/decreasing total number in js

Tags: javascript

I thought I had solved this javascript 'for' loop to sum up the numeric choices of several select fields to a number, each time one of them is changed.

But, modifying a choice in any of the selected fields is adding the number again, instead of replacing the initial choice number - which is what I want.

Example: a user chooses from 3 fields, these values: +15, -5, +1. 
The total should be "11"

If the user modifies their first select to +10 instead of #+15, the total value should be "6". Instead, it's ADDING the modified number to everything. So the number becomes "21" - not what I want.

Note: I want to increase the number incrementally with each select choice - NOT a total of all of them when the user is done with the fields

Here's what I've got:

```
<form action="/cgi-bin/dropdown.cgi" method="post">
 <select class="select0 selectables" id="dropdown-0" name="dropdown0">        
 <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" value="">select</option>    
 <option value="10">Choice 1 (+10)</option>
 <option value="-5">Choice 2 (-5)</option>
 <option value="60">Choice 3 (+60)</option> 
</select>
<br />
<select class="select1 selectables" id="dropdown-1" name="dropdown1">    
<option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" value="">select</option>
<option value="8">Choice A (+8)</option>
<option value="-10">Choice B (-10)</option>
<option value="15">Choice C (+15)</option> 
</select>
<br />
<select class="select2 selectables" id="dropdown-2" name="dropdown2">    
<option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" value="">select</option>
<option value="5">Choice ii (+5)</option>
<option value="15">Choice ii (+15)</option>
    <option value="12">Choice iii (+12)</option> 
    </select>
 </form>

  <div id="tally" style="">0</div>
  <script>
  var sum = 0; 

  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    var gg1 = new JustGage({
      id: "gg1",
      value: 0,
      textRenderer: customValue
    });

    var userSelection = document.getElementsByClassName('selectables');
    for(let i = 0; i < userSelection.length; i++) {
      userSelection[i].addEventListener("change", function() {
        fieldvalue = userSelection[i].value;
        fieldname = userSelection[i].id;

        if (fieldvalue > 0) {
          // using += breaks other scripts for some reason
          sum = sum + parseInt(fieldvalue);
        } else if (fieldvalue < 1) {
          fieldvalue = fieldvalue * -1;
          sum = sum - parseFloat(fieldvalue, 10);
        }
        document.getElementById("tally").innerHTML = sum; 
        // this is the value that takes the number I'm trying to increment based on choices in selects 
        gg1.refresh(sum);
        return false;
      })
    }

  });
  </script>
```

Comment: What is `JustGage`

Comment: What is `currentValue`

Comment: To get the best help, it's best to make sure your code is cleaned up and narrowed down to demonstrate the actual problem. You won't get any support if someone has to dig through your code just to figure out what you're trying to ask.

Comment: Apologies if that added confusion.. I thought I was adding clarity. JustGage is irrelevant to my question, but I left it in there so it could be seen what was being modified by "gg1.refresh(sum);"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because inside the callback function of the change listener you're not considering the values of the other dropdowns. Grab them using a second for-loop and recalculate the sum.

Here's your modified callback function:

```
for (let i = 0; i < userSelection.length; i++) {
  userSelection[i].addEventListener("change", function() {
    sum = 0;
    for (var b = 0; b < userSelection.length; b++) {
      fieldvalue = userSelection[b].value;
      if (fieldvalue > 0) {
        // using += breaks other scripts for some reason
        sum = sum + parseInt(fieldvalue);
      } else if (fieldvalue < 1) {
        fieldvalue = fieldvalue * -1;
        sum = sum - parseFloat(fieldvalue, 10);
      }
    }
    document.getElementById("tally").innerHTML = sum;
    // this is the value that takes the number I'm trying to increment based on choices in selects 
    gg1.refresh(sum);
    return false;
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever any of the select values is changed, you should re-compute the entire sum. Something like this:

```
  onload = function {

    var userSelection = document.getElementsByClassName('selectables');
    for(let i = 0; i < userSelection.length; i++) {
      userSelection[i].addEventListener("change", function() {
        var sum= computeSum();
        //whatever you want to do with sum
      })
    }

    function computeSum() {
      var sum = 0;
      for(const select in userSelection) {
        sum += select.value;
      }
      return sum;
    }

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Like others have mentioned, you need to recalculate the total every time any of select control value changes. Here's a demo (un-optimized):

```js
document.querySelectorAll('select').forEach(select => select.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
  if (allValid()) {
    document.querySelector('#tally').innerHTML = calcTotal();
  }
}))


const allValid = () => {
  let status = true;
  document.querySelectorAll('select').forEach(select => {
    if (select.selectedIndex === 0) status = false;
  })
  return status;
}

const calcTotal = () => {
  let total = 0;
  document.querySelectorAll('select').forEach(select => {
    total += parseInt(select.value);
  })
  return total;
}
```

```html
<select class="select0 selectables" id="dropdown-0" name="dropdown0">
  <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" value="">select</option>
  <option value="10">Choice 1 (+10)</option>
  <option value="-5">Choice 2 (-5)</option>
  <option value="60">Choice 3 (+60)</option>
</select>
<br />
<select class="select1 selectables" id="dropdown-1" name="dropdown1">
  <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" value="">select</option>
  <option value="8">Choice A (+8)</option>
  <option value="-10">Choice B (-10)</option>
  <option value="15">Choice C (+15)</option>
</select>
<br />
<select class="select2 selectables" id="dropdown-2" name="dropdown2">
  <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" value="">select</option>
  <option value="5">Choice ii (+5)</option>
  <option value="15">Choice ii (+15)</option>
  <option value="12">Choice iii (+12)</option>
</select>

<div id="tally" style="">0</div>
```